# "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

Tags: asp.net, directoryservices

I'm trying to use Integrated Windows Authentication combined with a DirectorySearcher to identify and authenticate the intranet user.

I'd managed to get some fairly simple code that seemed to do the trick, but when I tried on the live server I get the following error:

"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

I can't debug the app on the live server so I copied it across to an old development server to test there. When I ran the app normally, it came up with the same error, so the I tried debugging in VS.... except it worked perfectly.

I suspect it's something to do with impersonation or to do with the LDAP call - obviously when it works for the debugger it's hard to be sure what the real problem is.

But I figured one of you guys will be able to point me in the right direction.

Snippets from my authentication class:

```vb
Private Function GetUserID() As String
    Dim sID As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    Return Mid(sID, InStr(sID, "\") + 1)
End Function

Private Function GetDisplayName() As String
    Dim oSearcher As New DirectorySearcher
    Dim oResult As SearchResult
    Dim sName As String = String.Empty

    With oSearcher
        .Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", _UserID)
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
        oResult = .FindOne()
        If Not oResult Is Nothing Then
            sName = oResult.Properties("displayName")(0).ToString()
        End If
    End With

    Return sName
End Function
Private Function GetEmail() As String
    Dim oSearcher As New DirectorySearcher
    Dim oResult As SearchResult
    Dim sEmail As String = String.Empty

    With oSearcher
        .Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", _UserID)
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
        oResult = .FindOne()
        If Not oResult Is Nothing Then
            sEmail = oResult.Properties("mail")(0).ToString()
        End If
    End With

    Return sEmail

End Function

Private Function GetGroups() As StringCollection
    Dim oSearcher As New DirectorySearcher
    Dim oResult As SearchResult
    Dim colGroups As New StringCollection
    Dim i As Int16

    With oSearcher
        .Filter = String.Format("(cn=" & _UserName & ")", _UserID)
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")
        oResult = .FindOne()

        If Not oResult Is Nothing Then
            Dim iGroupCount As Int16 = oResult.Properties("memberOf").Count

            For i = 0 To iGroupCount - 1
                colGroups.Add(oResult.Properties("memberOf")(i).ToString())
            Next

        End If
    End With

    Return colGroups
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it much easier to use the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace for this kind of thing, in your case the UserPrincipal class is your friend.

```
Private Function GetEmail() As String
        Dim pc As PrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
        Dim wi As WindowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
        Dim up As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, wi.Name)

        Return up.EmailAddress
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem and I figured out that the cause of error was the way the url was written.

When using AD and ADSI ensure you are using "UPPER CASE" paths. As I can see from your code you are writing "cn" as lower case. [GetGroups function]

Another way I would try is to ensure that you are making a proper use of the "*connectionstring*" you are using.

LDAP://CN=" + username + ",OU=" + OU + ",OU=myOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2";

*becomes*

LDAP://**orgname**.ad.root/CN=" + username + ",OU=" + OU + ",OU=myOU,DC=myDC1,DC=myDC2";

where "**orgname**" it's the server name where AD is running on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may have been onto something here, but I have had opportunity to check because Jacob has tempted me with his UserPrincipals!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of achieving the same functionality:

```
string fullPath = "LDAP://abc.xyz.com/DC=xyz, DC=com";
AuthenticationTypes authType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
DirectoryEntry verifiedUser = new DirectoryEntry(fullPath, txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), authType);
verifiedUser.RefreshCache();
isAuthorisedUser = true;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that this is a permissions issue:  when testing locally on your development machine it worked because you accessed AD with your account. On the Live server, you probably run the application under a service account which does not have access to AD.